# Помогите расставить знаки препинания в данном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

я знаю чего хочу и на мой взгляд дал тебе это понять воду не лью пишу все конкретно

Answer (score 1):

Лучше оформить так:

*Я знаю, что хочу, и, **на мой взгляд,** дал тебе это понять. Воду не лью, пишу все конкретно.*

Основа первого предложения: Я знаю и дал понять.

Обособленное придаточное: что хочу.

Обособленное вводное сочетание: на мой взгляд.

Во втором предложении однородные сказуемые: не лью воду, пишу.

Comment: Почему *«**чего** хочу»* превратилось в *«**что** хочу»*?